# AS 2.0, Greensock, Animation fail

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2

I have an animation that slides across the x coord's on click of mybutton. 
  - Locally it works great 
  - on the Server it does not Animate on the first Click, but after that it works like a dream
  - I am loading the swf via SWF object 2.2
  - this is most peculiar, Has anyone experienced this? if so, Have you solved it ?

Code:

```
import com.greensock.*; 
rightarrow.onPress = function(){
       trace ("rightarrowb utton clicked!");
       trace (move_mc._x);
       TweenLite.to(move_mc, .5, {_x:-80});
    }
    leftarrow.onPress = function(){
       trace ("lefttarrowb utton clicked!");
       trace (move_mc._x);
       TweenLite.to(move_mc, .5, {_x:396});
    }
```

Comment: very strange. your code looks good. no reason for it to choke when hosted. can you share a link to the html page its in? or provide source files?

carl

Comment: More info*  this may help... This SWF is loaded into another, and the main file imports the greensock class prior to this clip loading. so I tested the system by commenting out one of the imports and it worked... So the problem is narrowed now to onload of this movie kill previous greensock class and reimport it...?

Comment: Solved** apparently I was calling the class in the SWF that called this one in... and it stutters for some reason... so to circumvent this I called Flashes built in tween class to do the movements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it might be a problem with focus within the page, rather than use onPress, try onRelease and see if it helps.